# Does photoeletric effect hold for all atoms or only hydrogen like atoms?

Tags: atomic-physics, notation, photoelectric-effect

In the reference that I am using, it is said that photo eletric effect holds for all atoms. However, to my understanding, this can be seen as a corollary of Bohr's theory. However, in his theory, the result is derived for only hydrogen like atoms. Contradiction?

Comment: Well, is the "atom" that is too specific. It holds true for isolated atom - independently of their atomic number. But the photoelectric effect can takes place from a metal surface, or from a molecule. What is general is that the Energy of the photon does correspond to the energy levels interval of quantisised states.

Comment: so... Energy of photon = ΔEatom = hv for all atoms or just one electron atoms?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Emilio Pisanty-okay it's okay thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The Bohr model was a useful step to the construction of a more sophisticated theory - quantum mechanics - which was able to model multi-electron atoms (and more complex systems like molecules), something the Bohr model cannot do properly.  In a Bohr-type model of an atom you can speak of an electron changing from one energy level to another.  This is not really the case in quantum mechanics where you must (ideally) treat the all the electrons as being in one connected state.

However the energy level of an emmitted photon is going to the difference between the energy of the initial state and the final state of the atom.

The key thing to remember is that *energy has to be conserved*.  The final system's energy (atom+photon) must have the same energy as the inital state (just an atom).

Comment: what if the atom absorbs n photons then it should be ΔE = nhv?

Comment: @ElieMakdissi  The photoelectric effect is seen in **conductors** where the energy levels of the electrons are with the lattice of the conducto, not with individual atoms. Individual atom interactions are just that, interactions .

Comment: @annav The photoelectric effect is present in both conductors and isolated atoms. The core of the effect (removal of electrons dependent on the frequency of the light and not its intensity) is the same in both cases, independently of whether you call the minimum frequency a "work function" or an "ionization potential".

Comment: @EmilioPisanty  sure,it is the same  underlying physics , but historically the *effect* is defined in conductors, and the n in  nhν is irrelevant to the effect.

Comment: @annav Perhaps historical literature from the early 20th century draws a distinction between the two. Current primary literature doesn't, and hasn't done so for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question isn't related much to the photoelectric effect. The only connection is that the photoelectric effect was among the first evidences suggesting that photons are discrete and carry a discrete amount of energy, according to the equation shown.

The third member ( delta E atom) of the equation says that absorption (or emission) of a photon occurs when the energy of the latter matches the energy difference between quantisised levels of the entity undergoing such phenomenon.

This happens in isolated atoms, independently of their atomic number, ions, and even molecules or lattices.

Comment: thanks a lot ^^